# Change training dataset aspect ratio and size

Tags: image, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, dataset

I have a training dataset of 640x512 images that I would like to use with a 320x240 camera.
Is it ok to change the aspect ratio and the size of the training images to that of the camera?
Would it be better to upscale the camera frames?

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you keep the aspect ratio of the images because you will be artificially modifying the composition of the objects in the image.  What you can do is downscale the image by a factor of 2, so it's 320 x 256, then crop from the center so you have a 320 x 240 image.  You can do this by simply removing the first 8 and last 8 columns of the image to get it to 320 x 240.  Removing the first 8 and last 8 columns should be safe because it is very unlikely you will see meaningful information within an 8 pixel band on either side of the image.

If you are using a deep learning framework such as Tensorflow or PyTorch, there are pre-processing methods to automatically allow you to crop from the center as well as downscale the image by a factor of 2 for you.  You just need to set up a pre-processing pipeline and have these two things in place.  You don't have any code established so I can't help you with implementation details, but hopefully what I've said is enough to get you started.

Finally, do not upsample the images.  There will be no benefit because you will be using existing information to interpolate to a larger space which is inaccurate.  You can scale down, but never scale up.  The only situation where this could be useful is if you use superresolution, but that would be for specific cases and it highly depends on what images you use.  In general, I do not recommend upscaling.  Take your training set and downscale to the resolution of the camera as the images from the camera would be what is used at inference and at that resolution.